# Active Backup for Business external VM

Tags: networking, vpn, backup, vmware-esxi, synology

I am currently playing around with "Active Backup for Business" and an esxi Hypervisor hosted EXTERNALLY by "Hetzner", a Cloud provider.
My goal is that when one of my servers fail I want to be able to immediately restore the server to the esxi host. there is a function in active backup for business called "immediate restore" which basically streams the vmdk file to the esxi h
ost.
However when trying this it always seems to try to access the Synology Server via its **internal** IP which of course doesnt work as its not in the same LAN as the esxi host.

Is there a way to tell Active Backup for Business to instead connect on an **external** IP or to create a VPN so my NAS IP can be resolved and the transfer can start?

I know it will be a slow connection as its over WAN however its just a test case so it doenst matter.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Active Backup for Business over a WAN. You will need to open up port TCP/5510 to your NAS and use your public IP address as the destination. It should also be possible to do the same across a VPN.